# SQL statment not running with the value of a hidden field

Tags: php, sql, hiddenfield

Peace be to you all, I am working on a "forgotten username" system and my code goes like follows :-

First form :-

```
`<form action="security.php" method="post">
  Please Enter your email address:<br>
 <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php $_POST['email']?>">
 <input type="submit" value="submit"> 
 </form>`
```

the php code:

```
`<?php
$mode_allowed = array('username','password');
if(isset($_GET['mode']) === true && in_array($_GET['mode'],$mode_allowed) === true){
  if(isset($_POST['email']) === true && empty($_POST['email']) === false){
     if(email_exists($_POST['email']) === true){
    header('location:security.php');
    }else{
         echo "Sorry, we can't find this email";
        }
    }
    }else{
        header('location:index.php');
    }
?>`
```

Now the other page:

```
   <form action="security.php" method="POST">
<p> Answer this question <p>
<select type="text" selected="selected" name="security_question" value="<?php $security_question?>">
<option name="security_question" value="<?php $security_question =mysql_query("SELECT `security_question` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' ");
                            $array = mysql_fetch_array($security_question);
                            echo $array[0];
                            ?>">
        <?php $security_question =mysql_query("SELECT `security_question` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' ");
                            $array = mysql_fetch_array($security_question);
                            echo $array[0];
                            ?>                  
     </option> </select> <br>
<input type="text" name="answer"/> <br>
<input type="submit" value="recover"/>
</form>
```

and its PHP:

```
<?php
include "session.php";
include "database/db.php";
if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
$answer = $_POST['answer'];
    if(!empty($answer)){
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."' AND `answer`='".mysql_real_escape_string($answer)."'");
                if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){
                echo"hello";                
            }else {
                echo "no";
            }

        }else{
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('you must answer this question');</script>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have also included a hidden field for the email:-

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>">
```

Now, the code works perfectly only when i ***remove*** the "email" part from the SQL statement!! what's the mistake here?!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the `<input>` a `name` attribute, so it will NOT submit with the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>"></input>
                    ^ ^^^^^^^^^^^---missing                             ^^^^^^^^--illegal html
```

Your HTML is fundamentally broken...

Comment: Actually, i was editing the code so i forgot to write it again and i have added it now and still it is not working!

Answer (score 0):

try to echo email within `isset`

```
echo $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

if here $email is not empty then use it simply

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `email`='$email' AND `answer`='".mysql_real_escape_string($answer)."'");
```

may this help to resolve....